# Rotate gameObject by applying rotation matrix in unity3d

Tags: opengl, matrix, unity-game-engine, rotation, unityscript

Is it possible to rotate a game Object by applying the Rotation matrix to it. Instead of passing each angle and rotating it.

I tried to use `GL.MultMatrix()` but there is no movement in game Object

Code sinppet:

```
    GL.PushMatrix();
    GL.MultMatrix(m);
    GL.PopMatrix();
```

The above snippet is in `update()` function. Docs says `GL.MultMatrix()` is similar to `glMultMatrix` in opengl library.Which we can use in openGl to Rotate right!!

If there is any method to achieve this please mention.
Thanks

Comment: From the doc "GL drawing commands execute immediately. That means if you call them in Update(), they will be executed before the camera is rendered (and the camera will most likely clear the screen, making the GL drawing not visible)." Did you try to put that in  OnPostRender() ?

Comment: I am not drawing anything on scene , just trying to rotate a game Object and I attached this script to game Object .I tried OnPostRender() also didn't work

Comment: I don't think you can do that this way then because here you are just pushing a matrix not assigning it to the gameObject and AFAIK there is no function that allow that with GL.

Comment: Is there any way to assign it to game Object and achieve it

Comment: I thing that ` GL.PopMatrix()` restores the computed value

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve but using **GL** for rotation probably is not a good idea. Have you had a look at **[Matrix4x4](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.TRS.html)**?

I don't know matrices well but I can tell you **GL** works with slightly different logic. You need to manually draw your stuff between the `MultMatrix()` and `PopMatrix()` commands using GL class (like `GL.Vertex3`) which gives you absolute control of how things are rendered but is redundant as hell.

Comment: I am not drawing anything on scene , just trying to rotate a game Object by giving rotation matrix and I attached this script to that particular  game Object

Comment: @javvajikiran , I agree with  @Nika  . Why do not try **Quaternion**, it is simpler and powerful.

Just like:

    `tranform.rotation*=Quaternion.AngleAxis(<degrees>, transform.right);
    //or Vector3.right`
[Wiki Quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion)

Comment: Yeah I can but may I know why the above code is not working

Comment: GL is for drawing new stuff, it will not redraw or somehow modify existing transforms in the game. Between `GL.MultMatrix(m);` and `GL.PopMatrix();` you shell make calls to `GL` drawing methods to draw stuff. Please see the example in the GL class documentation.